# Exception when converting base64 string to bitmap

Tags: java, bitmap, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to upload a bitmap to mysql table by converting it to a base64 string. When I try to use the image by downloading the base64 string and decoding the base64 string to bitmap it throws IllegalArgumentException :  bad base-64. The code I used to encode is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos); 
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
byte[] encodedImage = Base64.encode(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
avatarString = new String(encodedImage);
```

The code I used to decode is:

```
public Bitmap ConvertImgURIToBitmap(String imageUri)
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(imageUri, 0);
    //byte[] decodedByte = imageUri.getBytes();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

The base64 string is
 /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAFA3PEY8MlBGQUZaVVBfeMiCeG5uePWvuZHI////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////2wBDAVVaWnhpeOuCguv/////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAARCAEOAQ4DASIA
    AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEA

I want to avoid bad base 64 exception. How can I get around this problem? Please let me know in the code where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Wt is the line number of exception(which line of code)

Comment: byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(imageUri, 0); line in              public Bitmap ConvertImgURIToBitmap(String imageUri)
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(imageUri, 0);
    //byte[] decodedByte = imageUri.getBytes();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}

Comment: Are you sending that base64 string as a GET parameter, in the URL, or using POST?

Comment: You haven't transported the data completely. Show that code.

Comment: Hello EJP, you are right. I had not transported the entire data. The size I allocated for storing the base64 string is 1300 in the data base. While the base64 string length 130640. I had to increase the size of varchar in database. Is there anyway to reduce the size of base64 string?

Comment: You can't seriously expect to encode a bitmap into 1300 bytes of base-64. Only you know how big your bitmaps really are, but they are certainly going to be orders of magnitude larger than that. Why aren't you using binary and a `Blob`?